# How to implement method with generics in C#

Tags: java, c#, generics

I have such code in Java. How to make similar solution in **C#**.
Especially i'm interested **how to implement the first and the last rows**?

This code goes through specified package (that contains forms for Android and iOS) and returns Android form instance or iOS depending on *getTargetPlatform()*

```
public static <T extends Helpers> T getPage(Class pageInterface) throws Exception {
     Set<Class<?>> allClasses = new Reflections("forms", new SubTypesScanner(false)).getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    for (Class pageClass : allClasses) {
        if (pageInterface.isAssignableFrom(pageClass) && pageClass.getName().contains(String.format(".%1$s.", getTargetPlatform()))) {
            return (T) pageClass.newInstance();
        }
    }
    return (T) pageInterface.newInstance();}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a generic method in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144495/creating-a-generic-method-in-c-sharp)

Comment: By "first row" do you mean the method signature?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usecase, you could scan assemblies for your type. Example:

```
public static T GetPage<T>(Type pageInterface) where T : Helpers
{
    // maybe you need to scan different assemblies, depending on your usecase
    var allTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

    foreach (var pageType in allTypes)
    {
        if (pageInterface.IsAssignableFrom(pageType) && pageType.Name.Contains(String.Format(".%1$s.", GetTargetPlatform())))
        {
            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
        }
    }
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(pageInterface);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first row is like below:

```
public static T getPage<T>(Class pageInterface) where T: Helpers
```

and last row is just the same:

```
return (T) pageInterface.newInstance();
```