# C#: Return dynamic sql connection based on T type by generic usage

Tags: c#

suppose i am working with many sql connection object. some connect my local db, some connect my remote db etc

```
public static T GetGenericConnection<T>() 
        {

        }
```

so i want to call a function like `GetGenericConnection<DBLocal>() or GetGenericConnection<DBRemote>()` then `GetGenericConnection` will return sql connection object as T based on pass value. pass value means few class name like `DBLocal or DBRemote`

or i will call function like `GetGenericConnection<ConnectionType.DBLocal>()  or GetGenericConnection<ConnectionType.DBRemote>()` .

`ConnectionType.DBLocal` is enum type.

`GetGenericConnection` function will return `DBLocal or DBRemote` instance as type T based on pass value.

please show me how to achieve this with sample code. thanks

### UPDATE

```
public static T GetGenericConnection<T>(ConnectionType ConnectionFor)
{
    if (ConnectionFor == ConnectionType.LocalSQLConnection)
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType((new BBASQLLocalConnection()).Connection, typeof(T));
    else if (ConnectionFor == ConnectionType.ORCSWEBSQLConnection)
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType((new BBAORCSSQLConnection()).Connection, typeof(T)); 
    else if (ConnectionFor == ConnectionType.ReportConnection)
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType((new BBASQLReportConnection()).Connection, typeof(T)); 
    else
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType((new BBASAGEConnection()).Connection, typeof(T));
}
```

some kind of problem occur when i call function like this way

```
SqlConnection conn1 = (SqlConnection) ConnectionManager.Factory.BBADBConnectionFactory.GetGenericConnection<BBASQLLocalConnection>(ConnectionType.LocalSQLConnection);
```

Error message was

> Cannot convert type 'ConnectionManager.BBASQLLocalConnection' to
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Comment: Why don't you try it first, then if you run into trouble, we might be able to help.  We don't generate code for you unless you show some effort.

Comment: GetGenericConnection<ConnectionType.DBLocal>() I guess you mean GetGenericConnection(ConnectionType.DBLocal)

Comment: yes your are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a generic type parameter for this. Just a regular argument will do:

```
public static IDbConnection GetDatabaseConnection(ConnectionType db) 
{

    switch (db)
    {
        case ConnectionType.DBLocal:
            return new SqlConnection("dblocal connection string here");
            break;
        case ConnectionType.DBRemote:
            return new SqlConnection("db remote connection string here");
            break;
        default:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unrecognized DB Type");
            break;
    }    
}
```

---

Okay, based on your update I see more of what your problem is; you have wrapper objects for your connection types. What I'm suggesting here is still the correct approach. What changes with the question edit is that you also need to make sure your special connection wrapper types all implement a common interface.

Comment: This is a factory method.

Comment: i am curious to see it by `generic type parameter`. please post a sample code

Comment: @Mou You really don't want generics for this. You're making yourself do twice the work, adding complexity that will lead to bugs and hurt performance.

Comment: You can't do exactly this with a generic type because you would need a 'constructor taking a string in parameter' generic constraint which C# does not support. It could work if your connections were already created though (and that's the idea behind connection pooling).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn -- you *could* put a constraint on the type param so it has to implement the interface, but yes, still more work.

Comment: @rory.ap The interface would be IDbConnection in this case but you will not be able to call 'new T(string)'

Comment: what is the meaning of this like `T result = default(T);` taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2144509/728750

Comment: `default(T)` gives the default value for whatever type `T` the generic code is using when it executes. For reference types, this will be `null`.