# How to use PostAsJsonAsync as a generic function?

Tags: c#, httprequest

I need to write a helper method that would be reused for any class object. In short, I need to make PostAsJsonAsync method generic. Right now it is like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage POSTRequest(StudentViewModel student)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_BaseAddress);

        var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<StudentViewModel>("student", student);
        postTask.Wait();

        var result = postTask.Result;

        return result;
    }
}
```

If I use it like above I need to write it for every request for other viewmodel object. How can I re-write it so that it acts as a generic method for all the POST requests?

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144495/creating-a-generic-method-in-c-sharp and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this.
Preferred to use `async await`

```
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
                  PostGenericMessage<T>(string apiEndpoint, T typeofYourClass) where T : class
{

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("uri");

        var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiEndpoint, typeofYourClass);
        return await postTask;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do it like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostRequest<T>(T value)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_BaseAddress);

        var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<T>("student", value);
        var result = postTask.Result; // Task.Result waits for the result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.8
        return result;
    }
}
```

or async like this:

```
public async HttpResponseMessage PostRequestAsync<T>(T value)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_BaseAddress);
        return await client.PostAsJsonAsync<T>("student", value);
    }
}
```

i didn't see any type constrains on PostAsJsonAsync so it should be ok without `where T : class`