# How to create IReadOnlyCollection<T> method that returns generic data

Tags: c#, generics

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<int> FillData(this string[] ids,  IReadonlyCollection<int> list)
{ 
    var dataList = list?.ToList() ?? new List<int>();

    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        dataList.Add(int.Parse(id));
    }

    return datalist.AsReadOnly();
}
```

How to create Generic method in order to receive int and long for IReadOnlyCollection param and return the value based on requested type?

Comment: `public static IReadOnlyCollection<T> FillData<T>(this string[] ids,  IReadonlyCollection<T> list) where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible` - contrainst does not support OR operator yet for `int or long` but only AND with the comma • [Generics Level 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm) • [Generics level 2](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics) • [Generics in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/) • [Generic classes and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a generic method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144495/creating-a-generic-method-in-c-sharp) and [Is there a constraint that restricts my generic method to numeric types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types)

Comment: From [Preview Features in .NET 6 – Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/): *One long requested feature in .NET is the ability to use operators on generic types. Using static abstracts in interfaces and the new interfaces being exposed in .NET, you can now write this code [...]*

Comment: @OlivierRogier why did I not know this .net6 awesomeness, +1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work

```
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<T> FillData<T>(this string[] ids, IReadOnlyCollection<T> list)
    {
        var dataList = list?.ToList() ?? new List<T>();

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            dataList.Add((T)Convert.ChangeType(id, typeof(T)));
        }

        return dataList.AsReadOnly();
    }
```

PS: But keep in mind maybe you have to consider the culture.