# Attempting to create a Dynamic or T Type List for common method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where i am building a list of data from some source data. The exact same process is used by another source data so i thought to create a dynamic or List so i can pass in any data source to add the relevant data and bring back the object.

```
`List<customers> GetCustomers();
 List<products> GetProducts();

Public List<CustomerProductData> DataforCustomers (List<dynamic> myData)
{
   List<CustomerProductData> transformedData = new();
     foreach(var d in myData)
     {
       CustomerProductData cpd = new();
       cpd.Name = d.Name,
      //left out for clarity
     }

   return transformedData;
}`
```

1. What i wanted to do was pass in `GetCustomers` and assign `Name` but when i pass in `GetProducts` i would like to have `Title` instead of `Name`.
2. If this is achievable then either way i would return a list of `CustomerProductData`. I tried using `T` but i think the documentation i read wasnt clear for me to understand so im looking at some examples but i may need to an example to follow along with a class (i think)

When i did the following

`DataforCustomers(GetCustomers());`

I received an error of "*Argument type customers is not assignable to parameter type List*"

I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods
[Creating a generic method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144495/creating-a-generic-method-in-c-sharp)
and https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/generics

but the way i understand is these maybe suggest i cant do what i am attempting to do so would like to see what alternatives i have, if any

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this. One is using reflection, but in my experience that can be a little flaky and unreadable. Instead, I would suggest making the method generic and passing in a `Func` that gives you the property you need. For example:

```
public List<CustomerProductData> DataforCustomers<T>(
    List<T> myData,
    Func<T, string> getName)
{
    List<CustomerProductData> transformedData = new();
    foreach (var d in myData)
    {
        CustomerProductData cpd = new();
        cpd.Name = getName(d); // Use the func to get the property value
    }

    return transformedData;
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
var customerData = DataforCustomers(customers, x => x.Name);
var productDatadata1 = DataforCustomers(products, x => x.Title);
```

As an aside, I would almost always avoid using `dynamic`. Unless you know what you are doing, it is almost always a hack and can be dangerous to use.

Comment: Oh you made this look much easier. Let me try this out.

Comment: So far this looks like its getting there. The next question is within the foreach loop i have a small check which goes something like if(d.PropertyName == "abc") {}..... i dont have access to the propertyName anymore. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It depends, that is really a different question though.

Comment: Ok, would you mind pointing me towards what im looking for in that case so i can understand the differences (article link). I will mark this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select):

```
var customerPD = customers.Select(c => new CustomerProductData { Name = c.Name });
var customerPD = products.Select(p => new CustomerProductData { Name = p.Title });
```

This is a built-in extension method. There's no reason to write this yourself.